# string build injects a line feed or something every 1025 characters - messing up my sqlCommand

Tags: c#, string

I'm building SqlCommand string that builds SQL tables dynamically for DataWarehouse project.  I get column name, column type and appropriate arguments to complete the line and concatenate to previous.  Every 1025 characters a line feed or something is being injected by C# where it makes the line look like the following:  (notice`\nDiagnost`  is broken to another line.  Should be `\nDiagnosticResultsConfirmedByF200IEN` )  Really messes up the `SQLCommand` and is not valid.

```
\nDeepIncisionalSsi varchar(500) NULL,
\nDesiredProcedureDate Date NULL,
\nDeviceS varchar(70) NULL,
\nDiabetes varchar(500) NULL,
\nDiabetesCardiac varchar(500) NULL,
\nDiabetesMellitusChronic varchar(500) NULL,
\nDiabetesMellitusPreopMgmt varchar(500) NULL,
\nDiagnost
    icResultsConfirmByF200IEN varchar(50) NULL,
\nDiagnosticTherapeuticYN varchar(500) NULL,
\nDictatedSummaryExpected varchar(500) NULL,
\nDischargedViaF131x01IEN varchar(50) NULL,
\nDischargeTransferDate
```

The variable is `SqLColumns` and on this table the total length is `1025 x 21`.  This is one of our widest SQL tables with nearly 1200 columns.

Does anyone know why C# would be doing this?  Is there any way to work around it without busting up the create table statement into 1200 `ALTER TABLE` commands?

The code that is creating SqlColumns:

```
string sqlColumns = "";

 foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
            {
                // code to add columns to create table statement
                switch (row["DWFieldDataType"].ToString())
                {
                    case "varchar":
                        sqlColumns = sqlColumns + '\n' + row["DWFieldName"] + " varchar(" + row["DWFieldLength"] + ") NULL,";
                        break;
                    case "Date":
                        sqlColumns = sqlColumns + '\n' + row["DWFieldName"] + " Date NULL," ;
                        break;
                    case "numeric":
                        sqlColumns = sqlColumns + '\n' + row["DWFieldName"] + " numeric(" + row["DWFieldLength"] + "," + row["DWFieldScale"] + ") NULL," ;
                        break;
                    case "":
                        if (row["DataDomain"].ToString() == "PKIEN")
                        {
                            if (row["DWFieldName"].ToString() != dwTN+"IEN".ToString())
                                sqlPKColumns = sqlPKColumns + '\n' + row["DWFieldName"] + " varchar(50) NULL,";
                            sqlPK = sqlPK + row["DWFieldName"] + "  ASC ,";
                        }
                        break;
                    case "DateTime":
                        sqlColumns = sqlColumns + '\n' + row["DWFieldName"] + " DateTime NULL," ;
                        break;
                    case "int":
                        sqlColumns = sqlColumns + '\n' + row["DWFieldName"] + " int NULL," ;
                        break;
                    default:
                        //Code
                        break;
                }
            }
            sqlColumns = sqlPKColumns + sqlColumns + '\n' + "OpCode [char](1) NULL," + '\n' + "VistaCreateDate datetime NOT NULL," + '\n' + "VistaEditDate datetime NOT NULL" + '\n';
```

Comment: You say that it inserts "a line feed or something." Have you determined what the character is? It's *highly unlikely* that the C# string concatenation function is broken. Did you get that output string from the SQL server? Or did you output it from your function that builds it? Also, you should look into using `StringBuilder` to create your strings. It will perform much better than string concatenation.

Comment: No, I don't know what is being injected or how to determine.  I don't see how it can be anything but C# since  it's busting up column names and all I'm doing is '+' to concatenate.  How could it not be C#.  I can certainly try StringBuilder but this sure looks like a bug to me.

Comment: "How could it not be C#?" I can think of two things offhand: 1) there are non-printing characters in your field names. That seems unlikely, but possible. 2) Your database driver splits lines after 1024 characters.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're being fooled by Notepad itself. Even when you uncheck warp word, Notepad will break lines at 1025 characters.

Visual Studio's Text Visualizer has the same problem. There is a "Wrap" option at the bottom left of the window, but even when you uncheck it, it will not go further 1025 columns.

However, it is just a display issue - your string does not actually contain any line break. If you paste the result into an actual text editor such as Notepad++, or even the in the code viewport of Visual Studio, you will see that all the text will fit in a single line.

Comment: In another Forum it was suggested I was being fooled by the immediate window.  I think this is the case as he suggested sending to text file.  I did and couldn't replicate.
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\textfile.txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(test3);
            }

Answer (score 1):

I doubt `C#` is causing the issue. I guess it's due to you trying to append the string with `\n` (NewLine) character. Make use of the `StringBuilder` and it's `AppendLine` method instead.

Here's and example

```
     StringBuilder sqlColumns = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (DataRowView row in dv)
        {
            // code to add columns to create table statement
            switch (row["DWFieldDataType"].ToString())
            {
                case "varchar":
                    sqlColumns.AppendLine(row["DWFieldName"] + " varchar(" + row["DWFieldLength"] + ") NULL,");
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    sqlColumns.AppendLine(row["DWFieldName"] + " Date NULL,");
                    break;
                case "numeric":
                    sqlColumns.AppendLine(row["DWFieldName"] + " numeric(" + row["DWFieldLength"] + "," + row["DWFieldScale"] + ") NULL,");
                    break;
```

// Continue using the String builder as illustrated above

Then by using `sqlColumns.ToString()` you could get the final string.

Hope this helped to solve the issue.

Comment: I considered the newline characters being the issue but it's taking a column name like DiagnosticTestF335 and busting it into Diag                 nosticTestF335 and nowhere close to a newline character.  The only newline that I include comes at the end of a row.  I'll give StringBuilder a go but as stated above, this looks like a C# bug (undocumented feature) to me.

Comment: Ok, from where are you getting these column names? I believe there are special characters in these names. Find and filter them out. This is certainly not C# bug.

Comment: From a SQL table.  I can prove it isn't the column name by removing the previous column from the map and attempt to build the string.  It injects at a different spot.  That is it doesn't inject on the same column name as previous but always at 1025 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i have to put a long string into my code i normally bake it into its own text file and append add is as a resource. So i can also give this file a good file extension (in your case .sql) and if i open up this file in visual studio i also get syntax highlighting which massively improves readability. If i need just one or two parameters within this file I'm going to use simple `String.Format()` or if it gets complex use the [`.FormatWith()` method](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables). Even if you have larger dynamic blocks within your text result you should maybe consider to put all of these blocks into their own files and within your code simple refer to the resource string.

All this will help to improve readability of the texts and the code which uses it. But nevertheless there is still this mystic bug swinging around in your example. So I copied the string from your own answer (even if it is not an answer and should be an edit to your question) and did exactly as you meant (create a test2 with same; create a test3 out of both). I let all three string write down to disk and afterwards manually copied the first two files manually together. This manual approach i saved as test4 file and did a byte comparision of the test3 and test4 files. The result: They are binary equal.

Comment: I may adopt this strategy as I like the idea of having the script for historical purposes and possible troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

In another forum a user suggested my testing/verification technique was probably flawed and that the immediate window was probably the source of the injection.  He suggested I try writing string to a file, which I did and couldn't replicate.  So I believe the immediate window was the source of injection however, it didn't resolve the initial problem.

I went back to the drawing board and replaced all '\n' & '\r\n' literals with Environment.NewLine and re-ran.  The problem didn't pop up again.  So I guess those that suggested the issue had something to do with those literals are probably right.

I also like the advice given here to adapt the permanent strategy of writing to a file and invoking the file to generate tables since it gives a historical record.

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"d:\SQLScripts\textfile.txt"))
            {
                sw.Write(test3);
            }
```

After suggestions to try StringBuilder I altered code as suggested and StringBuilder does exactly the same thing.  Having said that, I think in my case where I have many concatenations I believe StringBuilder will be a better strategy now that I've resolved the underlying issue.

Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: This would be better as an edit to your question since it is not an answer. If you do find a solution it's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Comment: Perhaps but there is a limit of 30,000 characters and I needed to demonstrate really long string.  Normally I wouldn't take this approach.  Thanks for the feedback.